# Как перевести изображение в 8bit grayscale и максимально сжать его без потери качества при загрузке?

Tags: php, img

Доброе утро

Решил при загрузке изображений на сервер, переводить их в 8-битную шкалу, чтобы они на выходе были ч/б-шными и одновременно сжимать их без особых потерь, т. е. чтобы пригодными они были только для веб. Существуют ли встроенные функции или какие-либо алгоритмы в php? Можно ли в такими инструментами обработать, скажем, переменную $img, в которой сохранёно изображение при загрузке?

Вопрос, наверное, выглядит чрезвычайно нубским, но как я не искал, комплексного решения не нашёл.

Нашёл только `imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)`, но не ясно что оно делает с картинкой, не накладывает ли какие-либо фильтры увеличивающие размер изображения?

И какой формат при этом будет предпочтительнее (обычные чёрно-белые фотографии «журнально-газетного» качества): .jpeg или .png?

Попытался применить фильтр, но никак. Как же вот это `imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)` сюда впихнуть?

```
public function fileUpload($path)
{
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $image = getimagesize($fileTmpName);
    $extension = image_type_to_extension($image[2]);
    $path = 'public/images/uploads/' . uniqid() . $extension;
    $params = [
        'id' => null,
        'path' => '/' . $path,
    ]; 
    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $path);
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO `files` VALUES (:id, :path, strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))', $params);
    return $this->db->getLastInsertId();
}
```

Comment: так надо взять и проверить, что получится с размером. В целом jpeg это  растр, в нем нет каких то слоев или фильтров. Так что наложение чб фильтра меняет картинку. При сохранении надо возможно пошаманить  с настройками качества. Если волнуетесь за размер картинки, то возможно стоит ее еще обрезать/сжимать по ВхШ при каких-то значения превышающих лимиты. Если есть imagiсk какой, то вероятно он даст получше результаты чем встроенные gd функции и имеет побольше функциональных настроек.

Comment: @teran попробовал применить фильтр, но не выходит. Посмотрите пожалуйста в дополнении код.

Comment: а где тут попытки применить фильтр? Посмотрите в документации к `imagefilter` примеры. там вроде вполне себе написано, что надо сначала загрузить картинку через `createimage*`, потом уже с хэндлом что-то делать.

Comment: @teran в том то и дело, что потом невозможно продолжить манипуляции со значением этих функций в скрипте. `$file = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTmpName); imagefilter($file, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);` а дальше для `$file` невозможно применить `move_uploaded_file();`.

Comment: у вас два варианта: 1) сначала переместить файл куда надо, потом уже его загрузить, применить фильтры, и пересохранить 2) загрузить из временного, и сохранить уже как новый уже в вашей директории, тогда move вам уже не нужен, временный файл можно просто удалить. Второй, по очевидным причинам, будет более удобен.

Comment: @teran спасибо, есть теперь вектор, попробую реализовать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144334/discussion-between-linne-and-teran).